# Decrypting Bitcoin Wallet for Android

Tags: bitcoin-core

Does anyone know how to decrypt on a mac? I used `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in /Users/adriangonzalez/Desktop/bitcoin-wallet-backup-2019-06-26-22-20 -out ~/Desktop/file.txt`, but the resulting file does not show mnemonic 12 words.

I'm using Bitcoin Wallet for Android.

Comment: Bitcoin Core has never existed as a mobile wallet app.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer seconds after I posted my questions. I was not writing the code right, here it is

openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in /Users/adriangonzalez/Desktop/bitcoin-wallet-backup-2019-06-26-22-20 -out ~/Desktop/file.txt

https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md